# Como descreveria a conjugação verbal do presente do indicativo no seu dialeto?

Tags: morfologia, dialetos, morfema

Estou fazendo uma análise sincrônica do sistema verbal do português brasileiro e gostaria de saber como os verbos são conjugados no presente do indicativo no dialeto de vocês na fala coloquial. Com o fim de que eu possa concluir e analisar as modificações que estão ocorrendo na estrutura morfossintática do português brasileiro. Em meu dialeto (da cidade de Ponta Grossa, dialeto sulista), por exemplo, os morfemas do presente do indicativo são os seguintes:

- Eu -o ~ -Ø (verbos irregulares com alternância alomórfica de radical,
  tais como as formas **sei, sou etc.**).
- Você -Ø
- Ele/ela -Ø
- A gente ~ nós -Ø ~ -mu ~ -mos (estes dois últimos ocorrem em falas
  de pessoas com maior grau de instrução)
- Vocês -Ø ~ -m
- Eles/elas -Ø ~ -m

Answer (score 3):

**DIALETO CARIOCA**

padrão utilizado: verbo 'ser' e verbo 'fazer'; o 'x' é utilizado no lugar de 's' e 'z' para indicar o chiado relatadamente notável do sotaque carioca por outros dialetos

*Elevado grau de instrução*

- Eu: sou/sô; faço
- Tu: não utilizado
- Ele: é; fax (mesmo conjugação usada para "você" e "a gente")
- Nós: somos; fazemox
- Vós: não utilizado
- Eles: são; fazem (mesma conjugação utilizada para "vocês")

*Reduzido grau de instrução*

- Eu: sô; faço
- Tu: é; fax (mesma conjugação usada para "você" e "a gente")
- Ele: é; fax
- Nós: é/somu; fax
- Vós: não utilizado
- Eles: são, faz/fazem (mesma conjugação utilizada para "vocês")

Em suma, a substituição do 's' e 'z' no final de sílaba e palavras é ubíqua devido a sotaque quasi-inerente à região. Alta instrução tende a pronunciar corretamente senão por ocasional declinação de última vogal em um ditongo decrescente, e rejeita segunda pessoa por soar estranha ao brasileiro quando conjugada corretamente; baixa instrução erra na flexão singular-plural frequentemente, utiliza segunda-pessoa erradamente, e está submetida às mesmas variações fonéticas que a alta instrução.

Comment: Interessante. Muitíssimo obrigado pela ajuda em minha pesquisa.

Answer (score 2):

Brasília:

> Eu: passo / como / parto
>
> Tu: passa / come / parte (usado apenas no registro popular)
>
> Você / o senhor / a senhora: passa / come / parte
>
> Ele / ela: passa / come / parte
>
> Nós: passamos / comemos / partimos (registros culto e coloquial) /
> passa / come / parte (registro popular)
>
> A gente: passa / come / parte
>
> Vós: não utilizado
>
> Vocês / os senhores / as senhoras: passam / comem / partem
>
> Eles / elas: passam / comem / partem

No registro popular, o /s/ final da primeira pessoa do plural pode ser elidido ("nós passamo"), assim como o /m/ final da terceira pessoa do plural ("eles come"). E o pronome "você" é frenquentemente "encurtado" para "cê".

---

Porto Alegre:

> Eu: passo / como / parto
>
> Tu: passas / comes / partes (registros culto e coloquial) / passa /
> come / parte (registros coloquial e popular)
>
> Você / o senhor / a senhora: passa / come / parte
>
> Ele / ela: passa / come / parte
>
> Nós: passamos / comemos / partimos (registros culto e coloquial) /
> passa / come / parte (registro popular)
>
> A gente: passa / come / parte
>
> Vós: não utilizado
>
> Vocês / os senhores / as senhoras: passam / comem / partem
>
> Eles / elas: passam / comem / partem

No registro popular, o /s/ final da primeira pessoa do plural é elidido com frequência ("nós passamo"), e muitas vezes os verbos da primeira conjugação rimam com os da segunda ("nós passemo"). Também o /m/ final da terceira pessoa do plural ("eles come") é às vezes elidido.

---

O uso de "tu" é muito mais frequente em Porto Alegre do que em Brasília; com "você" (e sua variante internética, "vc"), acontece o contrário. Tenho a impressão de que "a gente" é mais comum em Brasília, mas não juro.

O /s/ final, quando pronunciado (o que é menos frequente em Porto Alegre), é sempre /s/ mesmo, sem chiado, em ambas as localidades.

Em Brasília, creio que por influência de Minas Gerais e/ou Goiás, tende-se a evitar a pronominalização dos (ou de alguns) verbos:

> Ela veste com muita elegância.

Em Porto Alegre, ao contrário, a pronominalização é muito frequente, até "excessiva", frequentemente soando como uma passivização sem concordância:

> Aqui se faz chaves por encomenda.
>
> Primeiro se passa na casa do Carlinhos e se pega a encomenda, depois se vai à festa.

Comment: Muito obrigado!

Comment: @Redwars22 Disponha!

Comment: Luís, cabe aí uma definição do que você considera "registro popular".  Quem são esses falantes?   No Rio de Janeiro, "Nós passa, nós come e nós parte" é usado por semi-analfabetos ou analfabetos virtuais, provenientes do interior de outras regiões do país. É considerado "um modo caipira de falar"  O carioca típico frequentemente fala errado: "dá isso pra **mim** ver" é característico.  Mas não ouço "nós passa" ou "nós vai" a não ser nos casos em que citei acima.

Comment: @Centaurus - Minha resposta é sobre os falares de Brasília e de Porto Alegre; faz muito tempo que morei no RJ, não sei se consigo descrever o falar de lá com precisão. Mas evidentemente, o registro popular é aquele falado nas ruas, sem preocupação de correção, nem de resguardo familiar. Não é o mesmo que o coloquial.

Comment: @Centaurus Aqui um exemplo de português popular (no caso, no falar paulistano de meados do século passado), por Adoniran Barbosa:

*Foi aqui seu moço / 
que eu, Mato Grosso e o Joca / 
construímos nossa maloca. / 
Mas um dia, nós nem pode se alembrar, / 
veio os homis c'as ferramentas, / 
que o dono mandou derrubá.*

Aí você pode ver o "*nós pode*", aliás alternando com "*construímos*". Isso é comum também em Porto Alegre - e, embora menos, em Brasília.

Comment: Sim, Luís, mas as músicas do Adoniram eram escritas, propositadamente, com erros diversos visando o humor: "De tanto levar frechada do teu olhar, meu peito até parece sabe o quê?  Táubua de tiro ao álvaro, não tem mais onde furar".  Mas, apesar de o meu conhecimento de linguística ser restrito, eu acho que há uma diferença entre "fala popular" e a fala do indivíduo sem instrução alguma.  .  :-)

Comment: Sim, minha experiência em Porto Alegre foi a de ouvir os gaúchos usando a segunda pessoa do singular (tu) mais do que no restante do Brasil.  E com uma particularidade: usando corretamente.  Mas a minha amostragem foi a de participantes de congressos, todos com nível superior.

Comment: @Centaurus - É, nós falamos assim quando tem cariocas ouvindo... quando não tem, tu nem imagina, nós falemo cada coisa... rsrsrs. Já quanto ao registro popular, acho que tem uma boa descrição aqui: http://alunosonline.uol.com.br/portugues/registros-ou-niveis-lingua-por-dentro-lingua-portuguesa.html

Comment: .........Valeu !